# Как на одной из страниц запретить include файла

Tags: php

Я делаю сайт, у меня есть два header которые подключаются ко всем страницам через **index.php**, header внешки, который подключается как **source/header.php** и соответственно личного кабинета **source/header_cabinet.php**, как мне сделать чтоб на определенной странице сайта хедоры не подгружались например к **source/qwerty.php** нужно чтобы только одна **qwerty.php** открывалась без header.

И еще вопрос как запретить к этой же странице **source/qwerty.php**. подключаться **css** которые автоматически подгружаются ко всем страницам из **index.php**
заранее спасибо)

Подключается так

###### index.php

```
<?
$nav = protect($_GET['nav']);

if($nav && $nav == "account"){
  echo '';
  include("source/header_cabinet.php");
}else{
  echo '<div id="wrap">';
  include("source/header.php");
}

include("source/body.php");
echo '';


include("source/footer.php");
include("source/gs.php");
?>
```

Comment: Это конечно всё очень плохо. Тут всю структуру надо переделывать

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можете воспользоваться `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` - выведет названия скрипта.

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/source/qwerty.php') {
    echo 'qwerty';
} else {
    echo 'header';
}
```